# TypeError: hostOrText.readFile is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, commonjs, rollupjs

I am trying to use [npm rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup) to make my repo into a npm module but I keep running into this error:

```
[!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) TypeError: hostOrText.readFile is not a function
    at readJsonOrUndefined (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:19519:74)
    at Object.readJson (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:19528:16)
    at getPackageJsonInfo (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44772:41)
    at loadModuleFromSpecificNodeModulesDirectory (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45350:27)
    at loadModuleFromImmediateNodeModulesDirectory (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45301:58)
    at /Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45291:39
    at Object.forEachAncestorDirectory (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8224:26)
    at loadModuleFromNearestNodeModulesDirectoryWorker (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45285:19)
    at loadModuleFromNearestNodeModulesDirectory (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45277:16)
    at tryResolve (/Users/mng/Documents/UI-shared-library/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44363:34)
```

Here is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import nodeResolvePlugin from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import { defineConfig } from "rollup";
import PeerDepsExternalPlugin from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript";
import sassPlugin from "rollup-plugin-sass";
import commonjsPlugin from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

const config = defineConfig({
  input: "./src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: "bundle.js",
      format: "es",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],

  plugins: [
    PeerDepsExternalPlugin(),
    nodeResolvePlugin(),
    commonjsPlugin(),
    sassPlugin({
      insert: true,
    }),
    typescript(),
  ],
});

export default config;
```

Package.json Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.17",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "^1.12.21",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  }

"devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.5.3",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "prettier": "3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0",
    "storybook": "^7.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": [ "**/*.ts" ],
}
```

tsconfig.rollup.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "composite": false,
      "declaration": false
    },
    "files": ["./rollup.config.ts"]
  }
```

These are all the file I believe are relevant. Let me know if there are any other relevant files I should share.

Thanks for your time,

-Matt

SOLUTION:

Downgrading TS from 4.9 -> 4.8 fixed this issue

Comment: That seems to be a typescript issue. Check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51644). Also, I tried running and it worked. I exported a simple function that logs hello world. I used node 18.17.0. I ran the rollup command locally, "npx rollup -c" to run from local packages instead of globally installed.

Comment: This was the correct answer, if you post it as an answer I'll give you credit for the bounty

Comment: I have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a typescript issue. Check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51644).

I tried running your project and it worked without any error. I did the following things:

- Export a simple function that logs hello world.
- Used node 18.17.0.
- Ran the rollup command locally, `npx rollup -c`. This command runs the rollup package installed locally instead of running from the globally installed rollup package.

Comment: Downgrading TS to 4.8 fixed this issue from the shared link

Answer (score -2):

To fix the error you're facing with npm rollup and TypeScript, first, update TypeScript and all Rollup plugins to their latest versions. Compatibility issues often cause such errors. Replace **rollup-plugin-typescript** in your **rollup.config.js** with **rollup-plugin-typescript2**, which is more stable and handles errors better.

Ensure your **tsconfig.json** and **tsconfig.rollup.json** are correctly configured. Pay attention to paths and options. In **rollup.config.js**, verify that the nodeResolvePlugin is correctly set up for handling node modules and TypeScript files.

Check the configuration of the CommonJS plugin in your Rollup setup, as the error might be related to it. Review your package.json to make sure all dependencies and peer dependencies are correctly listed and compatible.

Lastly, try clearing the npm cache with `npm cache clean --force` as this can sometimes resolve unexpected issues. ️

Comment: Please do not use `rollup-plugin-typescript2`. Use `@rollup/plugin-typescript` instead as it's officially maintained by the rollup team.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).